# What does being diffeomorphic mean in the context of configuration spaces?

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology

> A sphere space can serve as a "model space" for any configuration
>   space that is diffeomorphic to the sphere space.

This is a quote from my text book (*Principles of Robot Motion: Theory, Algorithms, and Implementation*, Howie M. Chose). What does *diffeomophic* mean in this context?

Comment: If $U,V \subset \mathbb R^n$ then let $f:U\rightarrow V$. If $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are both smooth then $f$ is a diffeomorphism. To be smooth $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{\alpha}}(x)$ should exist for all alpha. Where the points of $\mathbb R^n$ are given by the $n-$tuples $x=(x^1,...,x^n)$.

Comment: I was hoping for a more informal description...

Comment: @sas Another way of putting it is to say that $U$ and $V$ are diffeomorphic if there is a smooth bijection between the two of them.

Comment: Out of context, this quote is not really meaningful. You should provide some context and maybe a reference. The notion of a diffeomorphism makes sense only for smooth manifolds.  And no, a smooth bijection is not the same as a diffeomorphism.

Comment: In relation to robot motion, and their configuration space.

Comment: As far as I understand, In topology you can form object into different shapes, like a triangle can become a square (homeomorphic) but not a torus since the whole cannot be created(diffeomorphic).   

But this quote makes less sense, how would anyone use the sphere space to model anything that is  differmorphic, they have nothing in common?

Comment: As I said, this quote indeed makes no sense as written (it is either nonsense or a tautology which would mean that the identity map from the n-sphere to itself is a diffeomorphism). My suggestion is to first read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeomorphism for the mathematical definition of a diffeomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

A diffeomorphism is a smooth homeomorphism. (A homeomorphism is, informally, a function $X\to Y$ whose existence implies that $X$ and $Y$ are topologically "the same".)

So if we have a diffeomorphism $X\to Y$ then we know $X$ and $Y$ are "the same" in the homeomorphic sense. Many homeomorphisms can be smoothed out into diffeomorphisms, but if we have a very pathological homeomorphism then it may not be possible to give any diffeomorphism. This phenomenon, I am pretty sure, never arises for $3$-manifolds, but $\Bbb R^4$ has uncountably many structures which are homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic.

In any case, diffeomorphism of $X$ and $Y$ is therefore a stronger version of "the same"-ness, where we can expect the similarity to preserve not only topological properties, but differential properties as well. This point is a bit subtle, since no geometry must be preserved it is not necessarily true that *analytic* properties will carry over, but any topological results requiring differentiability will.

For instance, we would expect that any space diffeomorphic to the Euclidean $\Bbb R^4$ has an analogue of the mean value theorem, whereas a space only homeomorphic to this $\Bbb R^4$ might not.

Comment: For posterity re. “a diffeomorphism is a smooth homeomorphism” — this is insufficient; the inverse also needs to be smooth.